# Why is the copy constructor called in this code after the assignment operator?

Tags: c++

If I modify the assignment opreator so that it returns an object A instead of a reference to an object A then something funny happens.

Whenever the assignment operator is called, the copy constructor is called right afterwards.  Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    static int id;
    int token;
public:
    A() { token = id++; cout << token << " ctor called\n";}
    A(const A& a) {token = id++; cout << token << " copy ctor called\n"; }
    A /*&*/operator=(const A &rhs) { cout << token << " assignment operator called\n"; return *this; }
};

int A::id = 0;

A test() {
    return A();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << "STARTING\n";
    A b = a;
    cout << "TEST\n";
    b = a;
    cout << "START c";
    A *c = new A(a);
    cout << "END\n";
    b = a;
    cout << "ALMOST ENDING\n";
    A d(a);
    cout << "FINAL\n";
    A e = A();
    cout << "test()";
    test();

    delete c;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0 ctor called
STARTING
1 copy ctor called
TEST
1 assignment operator called
2 copy ctor called
START c3 copy ctor called
END
1 assignment operator called
4 copy ctor called
ALMOST ENDING
5 copy ctor called
FINAL
6 ctor called
test()7 ctor called
```

Comment: change `/*&*/` to `&` and this copy will magically disappear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because if you don't return a reference of the object it makes a copy.
As @M.M said about the final test() call, the copy does not appears because of the copy elision [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization][1])

Comment: How about in the case where I call `test()` at the very bottom? No copy ctor is called, only the constructor?

Comment: @Jason [copy elision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) occurs there.  Also that would be a move rather than a copy, if you are compiling in C++11 mode. To get a better idea of what's going on, disable copy-elision and add output for your move constructor.